# Theorem regarding the multiplication rule

Tags: probability

I am having trouble understanding this theorem:

Multiplication Rule.

Suppose that an experiment has $k$ parts ($k$ ≥ $2$), that the $i^{th}$
part of the experiment can have $n_i$ possible outcomes ($i = 1, . . . , k$), and that all
of the outcomes in each part can occur regardless of which specific outcomes have
occurred in the other parts. Then the sample space $S$ of the experiment will contain
all vectors of the form($u_1 , . . . , u_k$ ),where $u_i$ is one of the $n_i$ possible outcomes of part
$i$ ($i = 1, . . . , k$). The total number of these vectors in $S$ will be equal to the product
$n_1 n_2 . . . n_k$.

I know what vectors are in computer science and regarding precalculus/orthogonal types, but do not understand how they relate to statistics/probability.

What is this theorem saying in layman's terms?

Comment: You can have $n_1$ different values for the first term in the vector, and $n_2$ different values for the second  term in the vector, so potentially $n_1 \times n_2$ different values for the ordered pair of first two terms, and so on for a longer vector

Comment: If you have $u_1$ shirts, $u_2$ pairs of pants, and $u_3$ pairs of socks, the number of ways to put on a shirt and a pair of pants and a pair of socks is $u_1\times u_2\times u_3$. Every way to get dressed is an ordered triplet $(h,p,s)$, where $h$ is a shirt, $p$ is a pair of pants, and $s$ is a pair of socks.